# How to Display and Count multiple columns in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table named (Products) and 2 column named Apple(A) and Grape(G). Each fruit as value of 1's. I want a query which will count all the 1's under each column and display it with total count under each fruit.

A  G

1  1

1  1

I want output to show like below (Horizontally or Vertically)

Apple
2

Grape
  2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select count(Apple) as 'Apple', count(Grape) as 'Grape' from products
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that not all rows have 1, some have different number. so now when i run it, it counts all the rows and gives me a total count. How to get only the total count of value 1's :(

Comment: `where apple=1 and Grape=1`

Comment: oops i am facing a count issue. When i ran the query i am getting the total count but its kinda merging the count of the 2nd column were there is a NULL value. Meaning if my Current table has 3 1's in Apple and 2 1's in Grape it is giving me a output of Apple=2 and Grape=2 where it actually should say Apple=3 and Grape=2.  Any Suggestions?

Comment: please modify your qestion or create a new with new table with data and your sql.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26518236/how-to-display-and-count-multiple-columns-in-sql-2