# How to Display and Count multiple columns in SQL-2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Table by the name Products where column consist of Apple(A) and Grape(G).

```
A G

1 1    
1 1
1 Null
```

I ran the Query..

```
Select count(Apple) as 'Apple' count(Grape) as 'Grape' 
from products 
where Apple = 1 and Grape = 1
```

The Output which i get from the above query is

```
Apple=2
Grape=2
```

Where i should be getting Apple=3 and Grape=2. Kindly help.

Comment: `where Apple = 1 and Grape = 1` Grape NULL is not 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create table AppleGrape(A int, B int)

go
insert into AppleGrape values(1,1)
insert into AppleGrape values(1,1)
insert into AppleGrape values(1,NULL)

SELECT sum(A) as 'Apple',sum(isnull(B,0)) as 'Grape'
FROM AppleGrape
```

check fiddle too. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/126e05/5

Answer (score 1):

It seems this may be safer if you need a total. It handles null values more safely and doesn't depend on different behaviors from the aggregates default handling of nulls, which can trip some queries up.

```
SELECT SUM(ISNULL(Apple,0)) AS Apple, SUM(ISNULL(Grapes,0)) AS Grape FROM Products
```

Answer (score 0):

Your where condition is only including rows `where Apple = 1 and Grape = 1`
so the complete row with `grape NULL` is ignored.